# On Eclipse Console view, what key(s) move the focus to the button row?

Tags: eclipse, windows-7

(I am assuming Eclipse is supposed to be fully operable by keyboard.)

After CTRL+F7 takes me to Console:

[image]

what key(s) will place the focus on the Console button row e.g.

[image]

?

Answer (score 0):

Click <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to change focus until get to buttons row

Then you can move using the keyboard arrows signs

Comment: Thanks. from your info, I find just one SHIFT+TAB is sufficient to reach the button row https://i.imgur.com/Yqi9Jqa.png and a second ones reaches the Clear Console button of my example. Please do edit your answer so I can accept it.